# Jquery Full Calendar plugin with Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using the Jquery Full calendar plugin with Google Calendar. Google calendar returns me a Json response of Events List but Events are not displayed in my Calendar and give me the Error of

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)
>   http://localhost:22002/%7B%22kind%22:%22calendar?start=1385838000&end=1389466800&_=1386662028609"

```
(function () {
HRBC.controllers.Calendar = function () {
    this.load = function (calendarId, url) {
        //alert(url);
        $(calendarId).fullCalendar({
            events: url,

            eventClick: function (event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function (bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
                    }, 1);

                } else {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

url have all my Json Response, which is already JSON.stringify.

Comment: Can you show the JSON that is comming from server side, please?

Comment: @HenriqueC. Please answer the question on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541298/could-not-load-type-google-apis-requests-ierrorresponsehandler-from-assembly

Comment: I have never tried using a google calendar feed but actually i'm going to try it and see the JSON returned...i'll get back to you.